# Bar chart from Chart.js not showing the second dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

I have a `bar chart` from `chart.js` with two datasets, when the values from the datasets are far from each other, it displays normally. But when they are close to each other the value from the second dataset is not displayed

```
    const options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.1,
            categoryPercentage: 0.1,
            barThickness: 20,
            maxBarThickness: 8,
            minBarLength: 7,
            gridLines: {
                offsetGridLines: true
            }
        }]
    }
  };

  const data = {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of applications',
        data: [30],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    },{
      label: '# of interviews',
      data: [29],
      backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
  }]
    }
```

When i put 30 in the first dataset and 29 in the second one i only see the first one
[image: error]

When i put 30 in the first dataset and 4 in the second one it works fine, the problem starts after 9 (so 10, 11, etc)

[image: correct]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/7/26/f150d9b47f3fa839b01afff53478e5f3-full.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The y-axis starts at `29` so the 'missing' value, also `29`, has a height of zero.

Add the following option to start the scale at zero:

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true
  }
}]
```